# How to filter drugs by date , ex : marketing start date , or , listing_expiration_date

Tags: openfda

I am using the REST API Endpoint 
 https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=finished:true&limit=1

how to i  filter the drugs based on the created date or marketing start date etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by adding necessary filter conditions to the `search` query parameter just as you're doing it with `finished:true`. Please consult [this page](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-syntax/) for a detailed description of the query syntax.